# How to run JQuery in combination with other JS-frameworks (here: mootools)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions that i want to perform on a page. The first being some jQuery that slowly fades in my site upon loading. The second is some javascript for an auto scrolling div. The problem I am having is getting them to both work on the same page. Separately they work fine. The code looks as below:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.3.1-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.3.1.1-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scrollGallery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   var scrollGalleryObj = new scrollGallery({
      start:0,
      autoScroll: true
   });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (document.images){
     $('#container').hide();                        
     $(window).load(function(){                         
        $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;                        
        $("#container").delay(500).fadeIn(2000);                
     });
   }
});
</script>

</head>
```

Anyone any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong. I am still learning javascript so it might stand out as glaringly obvious to folks on here, in which case i apologise for my newby question in advance!

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two **entirely** different things

Comment: Just put your javascript code inside of the jQuery `document.ready`.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet

Comment: Combine both of the functions, as it stands now, you have two dom-ready events, probably causing some kind of havoc.

Comment: Also Jquery is JavaScript!!!

Comment: look into jquery.noconflict, you have conflicting libraries in mootools and jquery

Comment: Any reason you are not using jquery for both?

Comment: @Liam Where is she talking about Java?  I see only mention of javascript.

Comment: Mistyping JavaScript for Java is a very dangerous mistake here, you see.

Comment: @user1477388 Every other word in the question....

Comment: @user1477388 "The second is some java for a auto scrolling div.", "I am still learning java"

Comment: (Javascript === jQuery) !== Java

Comment: Is it more important to discuss about concept, than help to OP with answer?

Comment: @IMSoP That's obviously a typo since it's Java**Script** that she is talking about as shown in her code.

Comment: thanks user1477388, your comment was very helpful.

Comment: so what happens if the Op starts searching the internet for solutions in Java because they don't understand the difference. this is very relevant

Comment: Besides the common but very unhelpful mistake of writing "Java" when talking about the unrelated language "JavaScript", the *actual* problem here is the use of 2 different JavaScript libraries: MooTools and jQuery.

Comment: @Liam It's working fine for me: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+slideshow

Comment: @Wesley type Java for loop....top answer is Java the second is JavaScript.

Comment: @Epoc JavaScript !== jQuery. jQuery extends Javacript.

Comment: @Virus721 Extends? There is nothing you can do in jQuery that can't be done in pure JavaScript!

Comment: Define "JavaScript". I was implying JavaScript with the native API.

Comment: @SamFridayWelch No prob.  See my answer below.  Funny how your question caused a stir!

Comment: @Virus721 And how do you think jQuery was written? in native JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery isn't present in the native javascript API... Seems obvious to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your comments seem to have filled up I'll put this here

You will need to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) as you have 2 conflicting javascript libraries in mootools and jquery

As well as this, as IMSoP has pointed out, you will need to only use one DOMReady event and put all your code into one wrapper something like this (not tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   var scrollGalleryObj = new scrollGallery({
      start:0,
      autoScroll: true
   });

    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
       if (document.images){
          j('#container').hide();                        
          j(window).load(function(){                         
             j.fx.speeds._default = 1000;                        
             j("#container").delay(500).fadeIn(2000);                
         });
       }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `noConflict()` will be enough - all that does is stop `$()` being an alias for `jQuery()`. In this case there may be other issues attempting to manage DOMReady events with the two libraries.

Answer (score 4):

So, something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var scrollGalleryObj = new scrollGallery({
    start:0,
    autoScroll: true
  });

  if (document.images){
    jQuery('#container').hide();                        
    jQuery(window).load(function(){                         
       jQuery.fx.speeds._default = 1000;                        
       jQuery("#container").delay(500).fadeIn(2000);                
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

should work then? - I have definitely not tested it!

Comment: Doesn't seem to no, both functions do not execute. Thank you though for the suggestion

Comment: Try and find out, where the packages let you down. I.e. does *something* work? Do you get a message in the web-console? Can you maybe put in an *even smaller* "hello world" example in the jQuery section and find out whether it actually executes?

Comment: ... and just another guess: Does the variable `scrollGalleryObj` need to have global scope? If so, then it must not be defined with a preceding `var` in the `jQuery(document).ready`-function, but rather without the `var` (I have never worked with mootools ...).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option for you as per Dave Walsh's blog here http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

<script>

    //no conflict jquery
    jQuery.noConflict();

    // jquery stuff
    (function($) {
       if (document.images){
         $('#container').hide();                        
         $(window).load(function(){                         
            $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;                        
            $("#container").delay(500).fadeIn(2000);                
         });
       }
    })(jQuery);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.3.1-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.3.1.1-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scrollGallery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // moo stuff
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
       var scrollGalleryObj = new scrollGallery({
          start:0,
          autoScroll: true
       });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: sadly this causes neither functions to execute. Thank you for the suggestion though :-) always nice when folks try and be helpful

Answer (score 1):

[This link will help you](http://www.simplifyyourweb.com/index.php/developers-corner/90-solving-jquery-jquery-and-jquery-mootools-conflict-issues-with-the-jquery-easy-plugin).
When we are using two framework of javascript for Jquery we can use JQuery instead of $.
Even you can try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var scrollGalleryObj = new scrollGallery({
        start:0,
        autoScroll: true
      });

      if (document.images){
        $j('#container').hide();                        
        $j(window).load(function(){                         
           $j.fx.speeds._default = 1000;                        
           $j("#container").delay(500).fadeIn(2000);                
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
```